# Rules on gradient use

Tags: gradient

I am developing web - mobile apps and basing the navigation around jQuery mobile lists, e.g. [this demo](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/lists/lists-thumbnails.html).

I use [this tool](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) to obtain and change the gradient colour for each project. I mainly use a base colour and go from top(light) to bottom (darker) and this resembles the 'standard' way the default themes use in the jQuery widget.

I now need to follow through and use this as a backdrop for containers but if I use the same gradient in a container it looks different because of the colour spread:

[image: gradient example]

Are there any rules regarding this? Should I go top (dark) middle (light) bottom (dark) on the larger areas.

Any links on this dark magic appreciatted.

Comment: No. There are no rules regarding it. Do what looks good.

Comment: I prefer subtle gradients. Yours have a rather extreme range. If you used more subtle gradients the differences among devices would be less noticeable and I believe your design would be better.

Answer (score 3):

If you want your gradients to look consistent, your best option is probably to give it a fixed height and then extend the bottom color as necessary:

[image]

This means you won't have a gradient down to the bottom, obviously, but all the screens will look similar.